# Making master server slave of another master

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, master-slave, master-master

I have 4 MySQL servers Master1, Master2, Master3 and Master4.

Both Master1 and Master2 are masters of each other while Master3 and Master4 are masters of each other.

I want to make Master3 slave of Master1. Is this possible?

Following diagram shows my current setup in BLUE. The one in RED is what I want to achieve.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check multi source replication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html

If you are looking for general failover, I would consider checking latest technologies such as galera cluster (http://galeracluster.com/products/) or MMM (http://mysql-mmm.org/doku.php).

Each of them has some specific properties, so it is up to your requirements.